# When describing my PADI qualifications with a CMAS diver, is there a well know equivalence table?

Tags: scuba-diving

I'm currently in a French overseas territory, and almost all of the dive centres and clubs here use the CMAS system. Whenever I've booked in for a dive, the dive centre has looked at my PADI qualifications, asked a few questions, and put me into an appropriate dive group for the day. They seem to have always put me into the right group, so they at least seem to know the equivalence!

However, when I've been chatting with other divers (non-instructors) before and after dives, they've not known how to match my PADI level to their CMAS one, and nor have I for the reverse. This has made it tricky for us to recommend other dive sites to each other, especially ones in different countries, as we haven't known if the standard would be suitable or not.

Is there a well known approximate equivalence between the PADI and CMAS qualification levels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick reference :

```
CMAS                         PADI Equivalent
CMAS 1 Star Diver            Open Water Diver
CMAS 2 Star Diver            Rescue Diver
(with verification of Night and Navigation dive)     
CMAS 3 Star Diver            Divemaster or IDC Candidate
CMAS 1 Star Instructor       IDC Candidate
CMAS 2 Star Instructor       IDC Candidate
```

Source: [IDC Guide](http://www.idc-guide.com/diving-agency-crossovers.html)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to compare diving qualifications is to look at the ISO standards: 
[International Standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recreational_diver_training#International_standards_equivalence)

The International Organization for Standardization has approved six recreational diving standards that may be implemented worldwide (January 2007).

The listed standards developed by the (United States) RSTC are consistent with the applicable ISO Standards:

```
(USA) RSTC Standard              ISO Standard           Alternative ISO Title

Introductory Scuba Experience    No equivalent
No equivalent                    Level One Diver        Supervised Diver
Open Water Diver                 Level Two Diver        Autonomous Diver
Dive Supervisor                  Level Three Diver      Dive Leader
Assistant Instructor             Level 1 Instructor
Scuba Instructor                 Level 2 Instructor
Instructor Trainer               No equivalent
No equivalent                    Service Provider
```

Here is a table format of various diving certifications compared:
[List of Qualifications compared](http://www.scubatravel.co.uk/training/qualifications.html)

Comment: Can you add some context to this in case the links disappear in future? _Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline_

Comment: Will do. I just do not like replication of data/code/information :-D

Comment: mmmm ok so tables do not work, how can I create table structure?

Comment: Screenshot the table and upload as an image? Or do what @AM_Hawk did.

Comment: You shouldn't use HTML tables on SE sites, they don't format well.

Comment: thanks Liam already discussed with Aravona :-) Just put it in for now so as soon as I ahve time I can replace it with screen shots :-D

Comment: I completely forgot to do the edit hahaha so thanks for editing the first table. But how can people approve and edit that deletes a whole list without replacing it with improvement? Then I might as well have just left the tables of as per my first post in first place.

Comment: @AquaAlex because the first table was small enough for one person to easily edit - the second was a terribly badly made table even from a html perspective. An image would be better for that, because it removed the bad html, it did in fact improve the post.